# Is it possible to read and delete same row of table in sqlite3 database`@ same time using python

Tags: python, sqlite

I need a little suggestion 
I need to read a row & have a condition. If condition becomes true delete or update that row.. I am using cursor to read table. I wan to do like this.

```
import sqlite3
connection= sqlite3.connect('/home/User/Documents/attendance_report/program/data1.db')
cur_1 = connection.cursor()
cur_2 = connection.cursor()
cur_1.execute('select * from row_table')
for row in cur_1:
  if row[0] == 1:
    cur_2.execute('delete row from row_table')
cur_1.close()
cur_2.close()
conn.commit()
```

Note: I am using sqlite & Python2.7. Any other coding style is most welcome..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't you mean `DELETE FROM row_table WHERE id=?`. Your syntax is wrong.

Comment: May be delete should be written in that way.. I mean to say that delete that particular row which is reading at that particular time in for loop.

Comment: I believe you are looking for something like `connection.execute('DELETE FROM row_table WHERE id=1')`. There is no need to `SELECT` the rows first in order to search through them.

Comment: Yes I can write that one. But I write in that way b'coz I may want update if some more True which is I have not mention here. The problem is Sqlite perhaps doesn't support same thing to do in same table.. And also I want say you that I have to use cur_1..